# Li´s saindo da UL

Tags: css, css3

HTML e CSS:

```css
ul.ulVertical {
  border: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
    list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
}

ul.ulVertical li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

ul.ulVertical li:last-chield {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulVertical">
  <li>Passo 1</li>
  <li>Passo 2</li>
  <li>Passo 3</li>
  <li>Passo 4</li>
  <li>Passo 5</li>
</ul>
```

O que há de errado?

O objetivo é que as `li` fiquem dentro da `ul`.

**Saída**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma das forma de corrigir isso que vai ser mais elegante ao meu ver e usando `transform-origin`. Assim vc define onde vai ser o vértice de rotação, como vc quer que ele não saia da UL, vc define o vértice no `top right`

Normalmente por default o elemento rotaciona no centro do próprio `X/Y`, por isso "metade" dele fica para fora quando vc gira o elemento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já quando vc define que a rotação vai ser no topo a direita ele rotaciona a partir dali para dentro do `container`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```css
ul.ulVertical {
    border: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
    list-style: none;
    height: 100px;
}

ul.ulVertical li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: top right;
}

ul.ulVertical li:last-chield {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
  <ul class="ulVertical">
    <li>Passo 1</li>
    <li>Passo 2</li>
    <li>Passo 3</li>
    <li>Passo 4</li>
    <li>Passo 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: deu certo mas a altura (agora seria a largura? ) precisa ser a mesma da UL. Como fazer isso? Fiz com height : 100% e com width: 100%. Nenhum deu certo!

Comment: @CarlosRocha Vc quer que o texto fique centralizado no container é isso?

Comment: Bom, vamos lá. O objetivo é que cada LI tenha a altura da UL. Que a LI seja na vertical (como você já orientou na resposta) e que o texto fique centrado tanto na vertical quanto na horizontal dentro da LI

Comment: @CarlosRocha nesse caso vc não precisa nem do transform-origen então para controlar isso. Basta na UL vc colocar `display: flex;`e `align-items: center;` , sua UL vai ficar assim https://prnt.sc/mre6yq, se é isso que eu entendi que vc quier

Comment: Perceba que na atura, a li não preencheu toda a UL. Pode notar pela borda da li E outa coisa gostaria que usasse display: inline-block ao invés de Flex. Vai ficar melhor pra mim na hora de fazer as outras telas mobiles

Comment: @CarlosRocha então basta vc colocar width: 100px; e text-align: center; na LI vai ficar assim http://prntscr.com/mrek5m

Comment: agora até que deu. Mas tem o inconveniente de que existe uma separação muito grande entre uma li e outra, e não apenas os 30px de altura . Parece que ele está usando o width da li para definir um espaçamento, Como resolve isso?

Comment: @CarlosRocha vc vai ter que usar translateY() junto do rotate em cada item para fazer o que quer https://imgur.com/EGEIqX4 . Se não for assim a outra opão é começar tudo do 0 e usar outra técnica para fazer esse alinhamento, ou position:absolute nas LI e alinha um por um na mão tb.

Answer (score 0):

Basta um `transform-origin: 100%;` ou `transform-origin: right;`, que é a mesma coisa. Isso irá fazer o elemento girar com o lado direito fixo, evitando extrapolar a área da `ul`:

```css
ul.ulVertical {
  border: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
    list-style: none;
  height: 100px;
}

ul.ulVertical li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: .1px rgb(0, 0, 0) solid;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: 100%;
}

ul.ulVertical li:last-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ulVertical">
  <li>Passo 1</li>
  <li>Passo 2</li>
  <li>Passo 3</li>
  <li>Passo 4</li>
  <li>Passo 5</li>
</ul>
```

> Agora, tem um erro no seu CSS:

```
ul.ulVertical li:last-chield /* o correto é last-child */
```